# Почему у картинки добавленной через тег img плохое качество?

Tags: html, css

Вставил в вёрстку картинку через тег img. Сам файл картинки большого разрешения. Мне нужно, чтобы картинка была

```
height: 48px;
width: 88px;
```

Я эти стили в CSS и указал.
А картинка сжалась и выглядит плохо и с другими картинками, которым я указал высоту и/или ширину меньше, чем у оригинального файла, падает разрешения и они выглядят "мыльно".
Что мне делать, что картинки не выглядели мыльными на разных разрешениях?

В моей вёрстке картинка вот так выглядит:
[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V71mI.png

Хотя сам файл разрешением 300*185, т.е. большего, чем мне нужно.
Если не указывать в CSS ширину и/или высоту для тега img, то картинка выглядит на своё разрешение и занимает больше места в вёрстке, чем должна.

Comment: ну я может и ошибаюсь, но если у вас картинки 300*185, при пропорциональном уменьшении до 88px, высота должна быть 54-55px. Но не 48, как вы указали.

Comment: Konstantin, картинка будет мыльной, тк вы задаете фиксированную ширину и высоту. (Ниже представлен ответ, как сделать пропорциональную картинку с одним из задаваемых размеров). Если вам нужно именно такие размеры картинки, то вам нужно найти более подходящую картинку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы непропорционально уменьшаете размер картинок, попробуйте так - `img { display: block; max-width: 88px; height: auto }`

Comment: Я добавил ваш код. 
Всё равно картинка выглядит размыто.
Если не ограничивать высоту и ширину картинки, то тег становится в несколько раз больше и картинка выглядит хорошо.

Comment: а вы проверяли, может эти картинки (или их родитель) подтягивают какие-то ненужные стили? у вас нет ссылочки чтоб посмотреть?

Comment: https://geor-cpu.github.io/top-3d-shop/
Я говорю про 2 картинки рядом с поиском